# Php.ini disable "Scan this dir for additional .ini files"?

Tags: php, configuration, php.ini

I want to lock my php configuration and disable loading other php configurations rather than the default (which in my case is located at /usr/local/php/lib/php.ini) 
I want to disable the "Scan this dir for aditional.ini" or if there's a way to set the vars from php.ini as permanent I would go for it.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance,
Me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to do this you need to recompile php and remove the option `--with-config-file-scan-dir=/whateverdir/php.d`

Answer (score 22):

As an alternative that doesn't require recompiling PHP, you can set the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` environment variable. If you are using PHP as an Apache module, you may add something like this to the Apache configuration file in which the PHP module is loaded:

```
SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/
```

If using CGI/FastCGI you can also use the `-n` `-c` command switches as noted here:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45114

Comment: Much better solution. I'd rather use the system packages than recompile and manage it myself.

Comment: This actually doesn't work when PHP is running as an Apache SAPI module.

Comment: It certainly does work, you just need to make sure your server has mod_env enabled and available for your use.

Comment: I dont know how to do it man... its not working...

Comment: I added the environ var in the system, but still its not loading..

Comment: in debian and based : `echo "export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR='/usr/local/lib/php/conf/apache2/conf.d'" >> /etc/apache2/envvars` and restart apache2

Comment: Pretty excited I found this. I can now disable xdebug for `composer` only by creating an `alias composer='PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/an/empty/dir composer'`